# "В большинстве" - нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Они, в большинстве, живут в рамках материального потребительского мира...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужны. Только при очень большом желании можно увидеть здесь уточнение. *Они в большинстве своём живут...* – так ещё понятнее, что запятых не нужно.